# Invalid product version 'a.b.cd.xy'. Must be of format '##.##.####'. How to change the default version format to have 3 decimal periods

Tags: .net

I have a set up project with current version in the format "a.bc.xy". I want to change the version number to "a.b.cd.xy" having 3 decimal periods in the version number. When I changed the version number and hence also the product Code, and then built the set up project I am getting the following error:

> Invalid product version 'a.b.cd.xy'.
>   Must be of format '##.##.####'.

Can anyone kindly let me know, how to change the version no format to have 3 decimal periods in the version number?

Comment: Could you let us know which platforms you're using? It's hard to know what's complaining here...

Comment: Instead of including many synonymous tags please **indicate the platform**, setup tool being used, programming language, etc.

Comment: I am running a C#.NET  code in WIndows 7 platform. In my question a,b,c,dx,y are all numericals actually.

Comment: I am using "SetUp project creation facility" provided by Visual Studio 2005. Kindly let me know any other platform details I should mention.

Comment: Do you want to have version number to your application or to the setup project? Just to remind you application version is different from setup version.

Answer (score 4):

MSI supports a three-part version number format only. For some details about version numbering within MSI and Windows see [this blog post](http://www.installationdeveloper.com/979/a-close-look-at-version-numbers-in-the-windows-installer-2/).

Answer (score 3):

None of these answers fixed it for me.  I found a different solution:  in your solution, click the project (vdproj).  Look in the "Properties" panel (not the same as right-click.  Instead, press F4).
The last setting is called "Version".  It gets copied-in from your other project(s), and needs to be formatted #.#.# instead of the automatic #.#.#.#.
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand how this solved your issue. The only project vdproj I have found is from the Setup project, but then I did not understand what to do next. Also from your image I don't understand, removing the last digit is the solution, how can that be? then I think there is no solution...

Comment: Yes. the vdproj is the Setup project.  Don't "right-click" the project.  Instead, click the project and look at the "Properties" panel.  I was getting an error because the "Version" (see image above) only allows 3 segments.  You can see in my image that I was using 4 segments.  It seems strange that all MS stuff uses 4 segments, but Setup projects only allow 3.  Baffling.

Answer (score 2):

First you build Setup files using 2 decimal periods

EDIT msi using ORCA tool http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Open ORCA

Go to file menu click Open

Now select the MSI file and click OK

Orca will show list of attributes of MSI in the left hand pane

Scroll and Locate Property attribute

Now in right side search ProductVersion and change it to 3 periods

Click Save and close it.

Answer (score 1):

You cant change the format of the version number in Setup project as it is fixed.

If you are pointing at the version number for application which end user can see, then there you have four parts version number.

**Update based on your comment**:

To change the version of the application please follow below steps:

- Right Click on your application project and click on properties.
- Select Application tab and in that tab click on Assembly information.

In this window you can change the application version along with other properties such as product name etc.

If you use About Dialog provided by Microsoft then it will fetch application information from this area only.

Comment: Yes I am pointing at the version No for applictaion end user can see. Kindly let me know how shall I change that? I want that to have 4 parts.

Comment: My solution has many inter-dependent projects in it and 1 Set Up project. So should I change the version No: for all the member projects of my solution?

Comment: I'm assuming that each project might be a library but only one is windows application. In that case, version system should be used based on the changes and features you are providing in a particular version for particular project. If your end project is only consuming all those dependent projects and only this project is required to change version number for changes/features added then you dont need to change version number of all other projects

Comment: May be its better for you to get knowledge about how and when this versioning is used will be helpful.